# ¿No funciona sessionStorage en angular 17?

Tags: angular

En mi proyecto angular utilizo el código:

security.ts

```
import { HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
export class Security{

  static getHeaderOptions():any{
    let autentication:any="";
    if(window.sessionStorage.getItem("autentication")===undefined||window.sessionStorage.getItem("autentication")===null){
      window.sessionStorage.setItem("autentication","Servipack:"+Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,12));
    }
    autentication=window.sessionStorage.getItem("autentication");

    let requestOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json').set('Authorization',autentication)
    };
    return requestOptions;
  }
}
```

user.service.ts

```
...
  public getAutentication() {
    this.options=Security.getHeaderOptions();
    const requestOptions =this.options;
    let body:string = "";
...
```

Me muestra el error:

```
ERROR ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Function.getHeaderOptions (c:/workspace/hospital/src/app/util/security.ts:9:5)
    at _UserService.getAutentication (c:/workspace/hospital/src/app/services/user.service.ts:48:27)
    at _AppComponent.ngOnInit (c:/workspace/hospital/src/app/app.component.ts:52:22)
...
```

El código lo utilizo en un servicio de la aplicación, lo llamo

No se por donde seguir...¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: ¿Estás usando Angular Universal? En Node.js el objeto window no existe, pero todos los navegadores lo tienen, por lo que parece que no se está ejecutando en un navegador

Comment: Se ejecuta en chrome

Comment: No es accesible el objeto window desde ahi, no se porque, el type es undefined

Comment: if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
....
}